# How Digital Signature can be extracted from .exe using Java

Tags: java, file, digital-signature, signature, digital-certificate

I just want to extract the digital signature from a signed exe file using java without using other exe files such ah sign tool etc.,. Even extracting thumbprint is enough for my work to be done.

Comment: First you need to parse the Windows PE file format structure and extract the authenticode data. See the description [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx). Note that parsing data structures in Java is often a pain in the ass as Java does not have unsigned variables. Therefore you may think of creating a JNI library using one of the existing c code for parsing PE structure and create a JNI wrapper.

Comment: SecureBlackbox library ( https://www.secureblackbox.com ) has classes to handle Authenticode and validate signatures. Disclosure: my company maintains this library.